# Laravel trying to get property of non object error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make my own upvote/downvote system in laravel but i keep getting this error. **however this error only appears when the user hasn't voted on one of the posts that is being shown** as an example i'm showing all the posts to user and checking using getvote($post_id) function. the error only appears if the user hasn't voted on one of the posts however if he has voted on all of them then the error won't appear. here is my code to clarify more:

```
public function getVote($post_id) 
{
  $username = Session::get('username');
  if(isset($username)) {
  $uservote = PostVotes::where([
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'username' => $username,
    ])
    ->first();
    $vote = $uservote->vote;
   if(!$vote)
   {
     return;
   }
   return $vote;  
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

view

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
  <div class="container">
  <div class="posts">
  <div class="card">
  {{$post->getVote($post_id)}}
      <img class="card-img-top" href="#" src="{{$post->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">{{$post->title}}</h4>
          <div class="vote">
          <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-fw green" aria-hidden="true" data-value="1" data-id="{{$post->post_id}}"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-frown-o " aria-hidden="true" data-value="-1" data-id="{{$post->post_id}}"> {{$post->score}}</i>
          </div>
          <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted" id="getDate" data-date="{{$post->created_at}}"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i></small>
            by <a href="profile/{{$post->username}}"> {{$post->username}}</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error

> Trying to get property of non object error

happens because your code is not verifying that

```
$uservote = PostVotes::where([
      'post_id' => $post_id,
      'username' => $username,
  ])->first();
```

returns an element. Remember that the Eloquent model returns `null` if it doesn't match anything.

In that case `$vote = $uservote->vote;` will try to get the `vote` property of `null` - and this will throw an exception

Instead, check that $uservote actually returns an element with a simple if statement:

```
public function getVote($post_id) 
{
  $username = Session::get('username');
  if(isset($username)) {
  $uservote = PostVotes::where([
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'username' => $username,
    ])
    ->first();

    if ($uservote) {
        $vote = $uservote->vote;
    }

   if(!$uservote)
   {
     return;
   }
   return $vote;  
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: @flex_ This is because the $uservote doesn't return a result. I've slightly adjusted the code to handle this by replacing `if(!$vote)` with `if(!$uservote)`

Comment: thanks that did it. btw i just wanted to ask is this a good way to handle voting or should i use relationships?

Comment: @flex_ It is very difficult to answer without seeing your entire application structure - but there is nothing wrong with doing it this way.